# Can optimised builds and JIT compilation create problems when modifying a variable through a Span<T>?

Tags: c#, memory, compilation

Suppose I use `MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan` to access the bytes of a local value type, for example the following (not very useful) code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

// namespace and class boilerplate go here

private static void Main()
{
    int value = 0;
    Span<byte> valueBytes = MemoryMarshal.AsBytes(MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(ref value, 1));

    var random = new Random();
    while (value >= 0) // the check in question
    {
        random.NextBytes(valueBytes);
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

While this code works as intended, is the indicated check guaranteed to survive compilation to IL and JIT compilation, without being optimised to `true`, given that the variable `value` is not modified in the loop except indirectly via the `valueBytes` span? Can I rely on the read of `value` giving me what is written by the write to `valueBytes` or could this be vulnerable to reordering? Or am I just being paranoid because I've been dabbling in a bit of C++ recently?

(Note that I am aware that there are other ways to achieve the intended effect of the above code, this is not a question about how to get a full-range 32-bit random integer or an XY problem about some larger application which I'm trying to put this code into, no such larger application exists)

Comment: Excellent question! I guess it could also be expanded into how possible instruction reording might or might not mess with such a scenario (like modifying the int value through the span and then accessing the int value afterwards. Is it guaranteed or not that the C# compiler or JITer will detect such situation and prevent the span write access from being reordered behind the access of the value variable?)

Comment: @elgonzo - great point, I've updated the question to include that.

Comment: Sounds like you were bitten by the type punning rule in C and C++.  They did horribly abuse it.  C# does document the intention of the original rule, casting from a smaller to a larger type with a larger alignment requirement is undefined.  That's just hard processor behavior, mattered a lot more in the days of RISC.  Abusing the rule to stop checking for pointer aliasing, the truly evil behavior, that's not an issue.  Section 23.5.1 of the standard explicitly allows such a conversion.  Note that addressing at the byte level, like you did here, is defined in C and C++ as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, the only definite answer can be provided by the folks that implement the compiler optimizations, both on the Roslyn and the RyuJIT sides.

Since you're using .NET Core, you could of course dive into the source code and find an answer by yourself. This will be an answer for a particular compiler version, though.

Look at the generated IL code for your snippet:

```
// int value = 0;
ldc.i4.0
stloc.0

// MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(ref value, 1)
ldloca.s 0
ldc.i4.1
call valuetype System.Span`1<!!0> System.Runtime.InteropServices.MemoryMarshal::CreateSpan<int32>(!!0&, int32)

// the rest is omitted
```

Note that `ldloca.s` opcode. This operation [loads the address of the local variable onto the evaluation stack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldloca_s?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-2.2).

While I cannot provide you with an official link proving that, but I'm pretty sure both the C# and the JIT compilers will not optimize away that local variable - just because its address was used, so there's a chance this local will be mutated via its address.

If you look at the generated assembly code, you will see exactly this: the local variable is there and is placed onto the stack, it is not a register-only variable.

```
// int value = 0;
xor         ecx,ecx  
mov         dword ptr [rsp+3Ch],ecx 

WHILE_LOOP_START:
// ... do stuff

// effectively: if (value >= 0) goto WHILE_LOOP_START
cmp         dword ptr [rsp+3Ch],0  
jge         WHILE_LOOP_START
```

Try writing some code that doesn't produce the `ldloca.s` opcode (e.g. just `++value` in the loop), the `value` variable will most probably become a register-only variable.

If you modify your code in such way that `value` is never written to (except of initialization), the JIT compiler will in fact completely eliminate the check and the variable itself:

```
LOOP:

// Console.WriteLine(0)
xor         ecx,ecx  
call        CONSOLE_WRITE_LINE

// while (true)
jmp         LOOP
```

Interesting though, the C# compiler won't do that optimization:

```
// int value = 0;
ldc.i4.0
stloc.0

br.s WHILE_CHECK

LOOP_START:
// Console.WriteLine(value)
ldloc.0
call void System.Console::WriteLine(int32)

WHILE_CHECK:
// effectively: if (value >= 0) goto LOOP_START
ldloc.0
ldc.i4.0
bge.s LOOP_START
```

Again, the IL and the assembly code in my answer are platform and compiler specific (even CLR specific). I cannot provide you with proving documents. But I'm pretty sure no compiler will optimize away a local variable whose address was obtained and, even more, used as an argument when calling methods/functions.

Maybe someone from Roslyn and RyuJIT teams could give you a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for the information, this is fairly reassuring that all the recent changes do not seem to be borrowing the C++ foot-gun!

Comment: @dymanoid is correct -- because the local is "address taken" the jitted code should be suitably conservative and pick up the updates. And the jit does not do any "type based" alias disambiguation.